# Standard deviation question - how did they get this answer!? so confused!?

Tags: standard-deviation

Odwalla’s OJ is packaged in $250$ ml bottles and has a process standard deviation of $10$ ml.

In monitoring the fill process, $6$ samples (of $25$ bottles each) were collected and averaged:

- $249$
- $252$
- $253$
- $248$
- $245$
- $253$

What is the total number of bottles sampled? $150$

What is the standard deviation of the distribution of sample means? $2$ ml

The correct answer is supposedly $2$ ml but I keep getting a decimal answer.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 2):

The second part of the question is asking the following:  if the standard deviation of a **single** bottle is $10$ ml, then what is the standard deviation of the average of $25$ bottles?  Intuitively, the average of $25$ bottles will tend to have less variability than the variability of a single bottle, because the individual variabilities of the bottles will tend to cancel each other out.  The correct formula to apply here is $$\sigma_{\bar x} = \sigma_x/\sqrt{n},$$ where $n$ is the sample size, $\sigma_x$ is the standard deviation of a single measurement, and $\sigma_{\bar x}$ is the standard deviation of the average of $n$ such measurements.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the intuition part but when I use the (standard error) formula I get: =10/sqrt(150) = 0.816... instead of 2?

Comment: $n \ne 150$ in your calculation.  It is $n = 25$, because the question is asking for the standard deviation of the **distribution of the sample means**.  You are told that a "sample" in this case constitutes a collection of $25$ bottles, and you have $6$ such samples.  So your sample size is $25$, not $150$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$\overline{x}_1 = 249, \overline{x}_2 = 252, \overline{x}_3 = 253, \overline{x}_4 = 248,\overline{x}_5 = 245,\overline{x}_6 = 253 \Rightarrow m = \dfrac{\overline{x}_1+\overline{x}_2+\cdots +\overline{x}_6}{6} = 250 \Rightarrow s_{\overline{x}} = \sqrt{\dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^6 \left(\overline{x}_k-250\right)^2}{6-1}}$

Comment: The question isn't asking for an estimate based on the data collected.  It is asking for the standard deviation of the **sampling distribution**.  Those are two different things.